# while using flutter `esc_pos_bluetooth` showing error `Error starting scan. ` only in android 12. no problem below android 10

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Showing error while running in `esc_pos_bluetooth` in flutter I added permission in manifest page like this.
 `<uses-permission android: name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="31" tools:targetApi="donut" /> <uses-permission android: name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="31" tools:targetApi="donut" /> <uses-permission android: name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" tools:targetApi="31" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="31" tools:targetApi="donut" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="31" tools:targetApi="donut" /> <uses-permission android: name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`.
And still having the error.
 `Error starting scan. E/flutter (16326): [ERROR: flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Platform Exception(startscan, Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission for android.content.AttributionSource@8a7ab34e: GattService register Scanner, null, null)`.

this problem is only showing in android 10 or above devices only. under android 10 version phones support this smoothly and showing near devices also.

Comment: Which version of `esc_pos_bluetooth` are you using?

Comment: ^0.2.8 this is the version i used

Comment: and my project is flutter sdk version is sdk:  ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

Comment: Can you try 0.4.1?

Comment: no my sdk version is 2.7.0 so i cannt make it 0.4.1 maximum is 0.2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `0.4.1` with the following manifest on a real device works for me:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
```

What you are missing is the `uses-feature` flag. Check it out [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions#features)

You can also read about hickups für Bluetooth < 12.0 on Android [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions)

Comment: iam using  2.7.0 is there any way to print using this

Comment: Did you add the `uses-feature` flag?

Comment: @LOLWTFasdasdasdad i added the flag and it's not working with 0.4.1